# What is this color on mycelium?

Tags: mycology

i cloned yellow plearotus ostreatus to an agar petri dish, i used potato solution to make the agar.

the first 5 days the mycelium was growing in a tomentose growth and everything was right, the 6th day i started having yellow color in the center of the petri dish.
[image]